# How can I include active content in a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, cms, user-interface

Related to my How do I create a custom post type for a training CMS in WordPress? question, if I have a custom page type created for the presentation of training content, how could I include active content, such as a multiple choice test in some of these training pages? would very much prefer that the training page (i.e. my custom post type) is aware of the test, and acts as a micro-LMS, handling navigation back and forth between questions etc. It would break my cold, hard heart to simply plug the test into an iframe, so what else can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Use [shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) and put the logic into a separate plugin. This way, the forms aren’t bound to a special post type.